# Find number and replace by counter in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I want to find "1" and replace by counter 123...

```
{"wallpaper_index":"1",
{"wallpaper_index":"1",
{"wallpaper_index":"1",
{"wallpaper_index":"1",
{"wallpaper_index":"1",
{"wallpaper_index":"1",
```

Comment: what do you mean "by counter" here? Replace the number 1 by increasing values 1, 2, 3, 4...? In that case it's not possible to achieve in regex hence you need some external tool or add-ins

Comment: [Python Script - Plugin for Notepad++](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Replace the number 1 by increasing values 1, 2, 3, 4...  Can you give me an external tool or add-ins for doing that